# Format XML in Browser (asp.net, linq to xml)

Tags: asp.net, xml, linq-to-xml

Is there an easy way to write an XElement object to a browser so that it's formatted nicely, like this: http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/demos/UserInfoWriter.2.aspx? I don't want to have to create any sort of strongly typed class, or explicitly write every node.

Example:

```
var xElement = new XElement("test", new XElement("node", "1"));
```

can I do something with xElement at this point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you're trying to do, but if you change content type to `text/xml` the browser will display formatted XML. However, this won't work if you have other content you're trying to display on the page.

Comment: This works. This is the only line in my aspx page:
<%@ Page [...] ContentType="text/xml" %>

And this in the code behind:
Response.Write(xElement.ToString());

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried just using an XML server control and that doesnt meet your needs?  It is specifically for the purpose of displaying XML on a web page.

Here is the link to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/day7x985%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Well if you want to serialize that XElement object to the browser use e.g.

```
Response.ContentType = "application/xml";
xElement.Save(Response.OutputStream);
```

As others have noted, that is only useful if your ASP.NET page sends nothing but that XML document to the browser.